# MoviePy .cutout throwing out of bounds error

Tags: python

I am trying to cutout a theme tune from an audio clip. Here is my code so far:

```
audioclip = AudioFileClip(file)
audioclip.write_audiofile(audioFileName)
offset = findOffset(audioFileName, themeFile, 90)
print('\nFound offset: ', offset, ' - Writing audio file again...')
print('Cutting audio from', offset, ' to ', str(offset + themeFileDuration))
cutout = audioclip.cutout(offset, offset + themeFileDuration)
cutout.write_audiofile(cutoutAudioFileName)
```

It first creates an `audioclip`, then writes it a file and finds the start of the theme tune.  The big problem comes at the end when I create the `cutout`, and write_audiofile.  It gets to 3% and spits out this error:

```
      Found offset:  49.1  - Writing audio file again...
Cutting audio from 49.1  to  93.1
MoviePy - Writing audio in /Users/chud37/Desktop/Friends/output/120 - The Evil Orthodontist_cutout.wav
chunk:   3%|████▋                                                                                                                                                                       | 755/27881 [00:00<00:06, 3914.41it/s, now=None]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chud37/opt/anaconda3/envs/themeTuneRemover/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/audio/io/readers.py", line 193, in get_frame
    result[in_time] = self.buffer[indices]
IndexError: index -1842399 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 200000

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

File "ttr.py", line 94, in <module>
        main()
      File "ttr.py", line 91, in main
        convertToAudioFiles(files, directory)
      File "ttr.py", line 60, in convertToAudioFiles
        cutout.write_audiofile(cutoutAudioFileName)
      File "<decorator-gen-47>", line 2, in write_audiofile
      File "/Users/chud37/opt/anaconda3/envs/themeTuneRemover/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
        return f(clip, *a, **k)
      File "/Users/chud37/opt/anaconda3/envs/themeTuneRemover/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/audio/AudioClip.py", line 210, in write_audiofile
        logger=logger)
      File "<decorator-gen-11>", line 2, in ffmpeg_audiowrite
      File "/Users/chud37/opt/anaconda3/envs/themeTuneRemover/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
        return f(clip, *a, **k)
      File "/Users/chud37/opt/anaconda3/envs/themeTuneRemover/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/audio/io/ffmpeg_audiowriter.py", line 169, in ffmpeg_audiowrite
        logger=logger):
      File "/Users/chud37/opt/anaconda3/envs/themeTuneRemover/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/audio/AudioClip.py", line 86, in iter_chunks
        fps=fps, buffersize=chunksize)
      File "<decorator-gen-46>", line 2, in to_soundarray
      File "/Users/chud37/opt/anaconda3/envs/themeTuneRemover/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
        return f(clip, *a, **k)
      File "/Users/chud37/opt/anaconda3/envs/themeTuneRemover/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/audio/AudioClip.py", line 127, in to_soundarray
        snd_array = self.get_frame(tt)
      File "<decorator-gen-13>", line 2, in get_frame
      File "/Users/chud37/opt/anaconda3/envs/themeTuneRemover/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 89, in wrapper
        return f(*new_a, **new_kw)
      File "/Users/chud37/opt/anaconda3/envs/themeTuneRemover/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/Clip.py", line 93, in get_frame
        return self.make_frame(t)
      File "/Users/chud37/opt/anaconda3/envs/themeTuneRemover/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/Clip.py", line 136, in <lambda>
        newclip = self.set_make_frame(lambda t: fun(self.get_frame, t))
      File "/Users/chud37/opt/anaconda3/envs/themeTuneRemover/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/Clip.py", line 187, in <lambda>
        return self.fl(lambda gf, t: gf(t_func(t)), apply_to,
      File "<decorator-gen-13>", line 2, in get_frame
      File "/Users/chud37/opt/anaconda3/envs/themeTuneRemover/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 89, in wrapper
        return f(*new_a, **new_kw)
      File "/Users/chud37/opt/anaconda3/envs/themeTuneRemover/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/Clip.py", line 93, in get_frame
        return self.make_frame(t)
      File "/Users/chud37/opt/anaconda3/envs/themeTuneRemover/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/audio/io/AudioFileClip.py", line 77, in <lambda>
        self.make_frame = lambda t: self.reader.get_frame(t)
      File "/Users/chud37/opt/anaconda3/envs/themeTuneRemover/lib/python3.6/site-packages/moviepy/audio/io/readers.py", line 205, in get_frame
        result[in_time] = self.buffer[indices]
    IndexError: index -1842399 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 200000
```

It seems to be an issue within Moviepy itself, but how can I correct it?  As far as I can see from other examples i'm using the cutout method correctly.

Comment: How large are the files? What do you mean it gets to 3%? How do you know? See how to create a [mcve] and [edit] the quesiton.

Comment: The first `audioclip` file is 230mb.  Moviepy has a progress bar that reaches 3%.  The output from the print is `Cutting audio from 49.1  to  93.1`, those are the two values passed to `.cutout()`.